# Tagging all rows due to different information in multiple columns; Crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm running crystal reports XI.

I'm trying to tag all rows with an identifier if they're within the same group:

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok4zm.png)

Each group is made up of the same ID in column one, some rows have been flagged with the identifier "D".

I need to write code that will cycle through the results of the output and tag all grouped within "AAA" (in this example) that have identified with "D" to be removed. Only 1 or more row might be tagged with "D" however I need all "AAA" to be tagged with remove.

[Table with Tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0TBr.png)

I'm assuming I need to group them in some way but I'm struggling to work out how best to do this!

Thank you for your time and help! Apologies if this is a really basic question.

Comment: I'm not sure if the links are working, so I've created a capture for reference:
https://ibb.co/p2pWL4g

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a formula such as:

```
IF {ID} = "AAA" Then "Remove" ELSE ""
```

And place that formula on the detail section.

Comment: Hello, 

Sorry I think I wasn't clear, I need to be able to cycle through the results if the code finds a D in one row for "AAA" it then applies Remove to all those who are "AAA" not just that row, even if the other "AAA" rows that do not contain a D.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible if you are willing to group the report on ID.
IN that case, create a formula {@D_1_0} such as:

```
IF {Identifier} = "D" Then 1 ELSE 0
```

Then, add a Group Selection formula like:

```
Sum({@D_1_0}, {ID}) < 1
```